# enum to string in JPQL select query

Tags: java, enums, jpql

I am facing problem in converting `java` enum to string conversion. Please if you have any idea.

```
String mainQuerySt = "select o.ttType from Tt o";

Query mainQuery = em.createQuery(mainQuerySt);
List result = mainQuery.setFirstResult(offset).setMaxResults(numofRecords).getResultList();
```

I want the string representation of ttType `enum`. How to do it?

My `Tt` Definition:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
@Column(name = "tt_type", nullable = false)
private TTType ttType;
```

My enum `TTType` definition:

```
public enum TTType
{
    FC,
    PD
    ;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        switch (this)
        {
            case FC:
                return "FC";
            case PD:
                return "PD";
            default:
                throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }
}
```

I can't use `EnumType.STRING` in `@Enumerated` now since the system is live.

Please reply.

Comment: So you dont want to change value at Database level thats why avoiding ``EnumType.STRING`` ?

Comment: @rev_dihazum: yes, since it will require data migration and I want to avoid it. Thanks

Comment: your ``String toString()`` method is also failed to serve purpose? I guess it should work.

Comment: No, it didn't work. Result contains TtType instead of string representation which I want.

Answer (score 1):

One option may be to use enum constructor as bellow:

```
public enum TTType {
    FC("FC"),
    PD("PD");

    private String value; // the value

    // Constructor 
    TTType(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```